# How to create a heading in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, themes

I want to make a heading in beamer without any block.

I want to use the spruce color in my heading text.

I have attempted the following

```
\newcommand\myheading[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\Large\bfseries#1}\par\smallskip}
```

But it is using the simple black color text.

How to do it? Please help me.

Comment: `\newcommand\myheading[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\Large\bfseries\color{<desired-color-name>}#1}\par\smallskip}` ?

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example that shows which theme etc. you use?